Texlive on linux unable to compile
I have freshly installed texlive on mu Arch linux system, but I am going crazy after hours of trying to work it out.
I use it along with vs code with latex workshop. I was able to compile the document on other system, but each time installing tex, I run to some different problem with biblatex.
I get this:
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber main: gave an error in previous invocation of latexmk.


And than something about it can't read the main.aux file.
And the \documentclass is underlined red and saying this:
I found no \citation commandsBibTeX
I found no \bibdata commandBibTeX
I found no \bibstyle commandBibTeX
Package biblatex: 'babel/polyglossia' detected but 'csquotes' missing.
(biblatex)  Loading 'csquotes' recommended.LaTeX

when hovering.
Anybody wiser able to fix this?
EDIT:
Adding following files:
main.tex
\documentclass[twoside, 10pt]{article}
\input{./resources/def.tex}

\begin{document}
% TITLE PAGE

\def\VARTITLE{xxx}
\def\VARDESCR{xxx}
\def\VARAUTHOR{xxx}
\def\VAREMAIL{xxx}
\def\VARDATE{\today}
\author{\VARAUTHOR}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle=\VARTITLE,
    pdfauthor=\VARAUTHOR,
}
\include{resources/title_page.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TABLE OF CONTENTS
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newgeometry{textwidth=128mm}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BODY
\newpage
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\def\VARSHRMPR{0mm} %20mm
\newgeometry{marginparwidth=40mm-\VARSHRMPR, marginparsep=0.1\marginparwidth, textwidth=128mm, outer=16mm+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep-\VARSHRMPR, top=2.4cm, bottom=3.2cm, headsep=1cm} %mpw = 4.1cm
%\reversemarginpar

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\fancyfootoffset[RO, LE]{\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\textsc\VARTITLE}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\textsc\sectionname}
\fancyfoot[RE, LO]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
%\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hrule \vspace{2pt}\hrule height 0.5pt}

% MAIN BODY
\sloppy
% \include{resources/text/U1.tex}
asd

\fussy


\newpage
%\newgeometry{top=2.4cm, bottom=3.2cm, left=3.8cm, right=3.8cm}
\sloppy
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Seznam obrázků}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Seznam tabulek}
\newpage
% \printbibliography[title=Reference]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Reference}
\fussy
\end{document}

def.tex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,systeme}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{a4wide}
%\usepackage{minted}
%\usemintedstyle{vs}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} %[showframe]
\geometry{textwidth=168mm, top=2.4cm, bottom=3.2cm, marginparwidth=4cm, marginparsep=4mm,headsep=1cm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{sectsty}
%\usepackage[pages=all]{background}
%\usepackage{sansmathfonts} %helvet bookman lmodern tgadventor tgheros tgcursor courier arev iwona cmbright mathptmx fourier sansmathfonts sfmath roboto
\usepackage{roboto}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{bophook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true, %set true if you want colored links
    linktoc=all,     %set to all if you want both sections and subsections linked
    linkcolor=black,  %choose some color if you want links to stand out
    allcolors=black
}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{mparhack}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[style=iso-numeric,bibstyle=authortitle,sortlocale=cs_CZ, doi=true]{biblatex} % iso-numeric
\makeatletter
\input{numeric.bbx}
\makeatother
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}
\newcommand{\familynameformat}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}{\familynameformat}%
}
\addbibresource{./resources/ref.bib}

%\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}

% \usepackage{eso-pic}
% \AddToShipoutPictureFG{%
% \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
% \path (current page.south west) -- (current page.north east)
%  node[midway,scale=25,color=blue2,sloped, opacity=0.2] {\textbf{ČVUT}};
% \end{tikzpicture}
% }
% \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}
% \setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
% \newacronym{cvut}{ČVUT}{České Vysoké Učení Technické}
% \makeglossaries
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage[lof, lot]{multitoc}
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{2}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\intextsep}{2pt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

main.log - all the red marked warnings
LaTeX Warning: Command \underbar  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.


LaTeX Warning: Command \underline  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

LaTeX Warning: Command \@footnotemark  has changed.
               Check if current package is valid.

Package marginnote Warning: Consecutive odd pages found.
(marginnote)                Note, it is not recommended to use consecutive
(marginnote)                odd pages in a double-ended document.
(marginnote)                The pages of your document should always
(marginnote)                be a sequence: odd-even-odd-even-...
(marginnote)                Maybe you've forgotten a \cleardoublepage before
(marginnote)                changing the page numbering on page 1.

Package mparhack Warning: Marginpars may have changed.
(mparhack)                Rerun to get them right.

)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 ***********


Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `main.out' has changed.
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

settings.json
{
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

    
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "--shell-escape", // added arg to default
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",////
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [
             "-synctex=1",
             "-interaction=nonstopmode",
             "-file-line-error",
             "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "--shell-escape", // added arg to default
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "command": "bibtex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
        {
            "name": "tectonic",
            "command": "tectonic",
            "args": ["-X", "build", "--keep-intermediates", "--keep-logs"],
            "env": {}
          }
    ],

    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.pdf": "latex-workshop-pdf-hook"
    },
    "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [
        "james-yu.latex-workshop"
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [

        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (latexmkrc)",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk_rconly"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (lualatex)",
            "tools": [
                "lualatexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk (xelatex)",
            "tools": [
                "xelatexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex * 2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "bibtex",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Rnw files",
            "tools": [
                "rnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Jnw files",
            "tools": [
                "jnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Compile Pnw files",
            "tools": [
                "pnw2tex",
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "tectonic",
            "tools": ["tectonic"]
        }
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onSave",
    "latex-workshop.intellisense.biblatexJSON.replace": {

    },
    "latex-workshop.intellisense.citation.backend": "biblatex",
    // "latex-workshop.latex.clean.command": "",
    // "latex-workshop.latex.recipe.default": "tectonic",
    // "latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "onSave",
    // "latex-workshop.latex.outDir": "%WORKSPACE_FOLDER%/build/index",
    // "latex-workshop.view.pdf.viewer": "tab",
    // "latex-workshop.intellisense.biblatexJSON.replace": {
        
    // },
    // "latex-workshop.latex.rootFile.indicator": "\\begin{document}",
}


welccome! can you compile on the command line if you run the various steps manually in the working directory? are you using bibtex or biber/biblatex? you've tagged the question bibtex but you say the error is from biber and are clearly loading biblatex. please post the first error from the .log file - not the summary your editor displays.

@cfr I might disappoint you with my answer, but excuse my inexperience please. I have set Latex Workshop in VS Code to use bibtex as backend, I use biblatex as tex package and have no idea where biber comes from. The .log file is full of infos and warnings, but I can't find any errors written in there, although they should be there...

Biblatex uses biber by default. please provide code we can use to reproduce the problem. but if you are running bibtex and haven't told Biblatex explicitly you want to run in that mode, it won't work. similarly, if you are set up for bibtex, but run biber, that won't work. unless you have very good reason to do otherwise, you should use biber with Biblatex.

you have not shown your input or the error messages, just your paraphrasing of the summary of error messages produced by your editor. There is no information here that makes any answer possible.

You should make a single self contained document, and remove anything unrelevant. Also, ignore your editor for now an compile from the command line (just in case your editor does something strange, or you have setup your LaTeX in a way that calling latex from cli or editor gives different results). Also, compiling from the cli ignores the editors (bad) log filtering.

@daleif I compiled new text file containing just documentclass and begin/end document with one word and I've done it from command line with latexmk and pdflatex. Latexmk hasn't produced any pdf, but pdflatex did work. Although I still get the same message as in VS Code, that there is no file main.aux. Then I tried to compile my original project and it compiled from command line and hasn't from the VS Code builder

Remember for latexmk you need latexmk -pdf in order for it to run pdflatex.

then the issue is your editor config since the code itself compiles on the command line. assuming you're using latexmk in vs code, remove the outdir and use the working directory for generated files (at least while troubleshooting).
